# Python: iterate over iterable and saclar simultaneously with zip-like funciton

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterable

First of all: feel free to edit the title of the question to make it clearer.

I'm writing a function that can take both scalars and array-like ojects for a number of inputs. Regardless of the type of input the behaviour should be the same: I eventualy want to iterate over the input. If it was a scalar, the iteration should return tht same sacalar every time. A mock-up code would be (using a `ziplike` function):

```
a_string = 'Some characters'
a_number = 2
for s,n in ziplike(a_string,a_number):
   print(s,n)
```

this would return

```
S 2
o 2
m 2 
...
```

But if `a_number` were to be a list, for example, I'd like it to behave just like zip. I'm not necessarily looking to write this `ziplike` funtion, since I can test for the input beforehand:

```
import numpy as np
if np.isscalar(a_number): 
   a_number = [a_number] * len(a_string)
for s,n in zip(a_numbber,a_string): ...
```

I was just wondering if there is an in-built (or at least simpler than checking each variable) way to do this.

I'll paste here the a simplified version of the coed I'm currently using. It generates a number of sine waves with diferent frequencies, useful to check frequency responce of some circuit. The user should be able to input the frequencies themselves or the starting requency, the final frequency and the step size. In this example, the amplitude and duration of each sine should be constant given by the `amplitude` and `duration` values, if they are sacalar, of different for each frequency, if they are iterables.

```
import numpy as np
def swipe(freqs=np.arrange(100,100,10), amplitude=1, duration=1):
    ''' 
    Yields a numer of sine waves wit desired frequency, amplitude and duration.

        freqs: tuple or array-like
            If tuple, it should be (start,stop,step) containing frequencies in
            Hz. If array-like, it should contain frequencies to sweep.
        ampliutde: float or array-like
            Aplitude of the generated signal. If array like, len(amplitude)
            sholud be equal to amount of frequencies to sweep. 
        duration: float or array-like
            Duration of each frequency. If array like, len(amplitude) sholud be
            equal to amount of frequencies to sweep.
    '''

    if isinstance(freqs,tuple):
        freqs = np.arange(freqs[0],freqs[1],freqs[2])

    N_freq = len(freqs)

    if np.isscalar(amplitude):
        amplitude = [amplitude] * N_freq

    if np.isscalar(duration):
        duration = [duration] * N_freq

    for freq, amp, dur in zip(freqs,amplitude,duration):
        time = np.arrange(0,dur,.01)
        wave = amp * np.sin(2 * np.pi * freq * time)
        yield wave
```

Comment: I'd just make the caller of `swipe` responsible for providing an appropriate iterable, possibly using `itertools.repeat`. If that means calling `swipe(x, repeat(amp), repeat(dur))` instead of `swipe(x, amp, dur)`, so be it.

Comment: Yeah, that' the idea, but `repeat([1,2,3])` will yield `[1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3], `, won't it? I''d need such a solution that works with both iterables and scalars alike.

Comment: Yes, so don't do that. It simply isn't (or shouldn't be) the responsibility of `swipe` to detect this kind of thing. If the caller wants a series of 1s, they should be explicit instead of expecting `swipe` to turn `1` into such a series.

Comment: The caller will be predominantly me, so t is me That ould like that functionality. As I said, I got it working with the checks I wrote in the working example. I was just wondering if tehre was an easier way.